# Laravel object values don't exist, but then do if json_encoded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There's something weird going on in my Laravel query.

So I'm getting a collection of `Users` - if I run it through `json_encode`, all its keys/values are there. If I don't, some of them are null. E.g:

```
        Log::info(json_encode($user)); // 'tasks_from_columns' exists
        Log::info($user->tasks_from_columns); // null
        Log::info($user->email); // exists?
        Log::info(get_object_vars($user)); // 'incrementing', 'exists', 'wasRecentlyCreated', 'timestamps'
```

There's a relation on the `User` called `tasks_from_columns`. It's there if I `json_encode` it, but null if I try to access it directly. Most other keys are accessible though, like `email`, `id` etc.

If I run it through `get_object_vars`, none of them are shown. Just some other ones shown above.

Anyone know what the deal is?

The query itself is

```
        $teamWithTasks = Team::where('id',$team->id)->with(['users' => function($query) use($team){
            $query->with(['tasksFromColumns' => function($secondQuery) use($team){
                $secondQuery->where('created_at','>',Carbon::now()->subDays(365))->with('project')->whereHas('project', function($thirdQuery) use ($team){
                    $thirdQuery->where('account_id', $team->account_id);
                });
            }]);
        }])->first();
```

Comment: There's not actually a property on the class like `email`. Laravel uses PHP's `__get()` magic method (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) to provide that, so it won't be in `get_object_vars`. It's in `json_encode` because Eloquent objects [are set up to be JSON serializable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php).

Comment: @ceejayoz that part makes sense, but how come `tasks_from_columns` is null despite having been loaded? 

For now I'm just running the whole result through `json_encode` then `json_decode` but that feels dumb. Works though...

Comment: Can you share your relationship definition? Have you tried using `with()` to eager-load the relationship?

Comment: Sure thing - I've popped it in above (sorry, it's a bit of a dense one!)

Comment: Looking at your query, seems that your relationship function name is `tasksFromColumns` (and not `tasks_from_columns`) , so `$user->tasksFromColumns` should give you the expected values.

Comment: Laravel returns all camel-case methods as snake-case, though - the JSON-encoded object is in snake-case, so it's still doing so. 

If I try to access `$user->tasksFromColumns`, it runs another query 

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Laravel does not returns all camelCase methods as snake_case, it only converts them to snake_case upon serialization.

Comment: On the instance of a model, to access a relationship that has been loaded with eager loading, use the magic method with the name of the relationship (since it has been loaded with eagerloaded, laravel does not have to run another query). For the case of the query that you show in the question: `$teamWithTasks->users->each(function ($user) { dump($user->tasksFromColumns); });`.